# How can I get the value of a combobox into a string in vba module?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a form that [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTjk0.png) exports do xml based on query. That query is build with the conditions of combobox.
The combobox have only one field.
What I want is to, in vba module, name de xml file with the conditions of the combobox.

Example: value of combobox: 03, Lucas, Roger, 23.

file: myXML.Save "C:\teste\03_Lucas_Roger_23.xml"

Comment: is this on an access form?

Comment: yes, i am using acess 2010

Comment: web search "How to concatenate strings in VBA"

Comment: My problem is not that, i Know how to concatenate. My problem is put into a string the value of the combobox.

Comment: How are you generating the xml, have you tackled all that without knowing the `.value` property?

Comment: You're getting two different answers, because they both think you're asking different things. Please try to be clear about the exact problem.

Comment: Dim rs              As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn              As ADODB.Connection Dim myXML           As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim myXSLT          As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim sSQL            As String

    Set myXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    myXML.async = False
    myXML.preserveWhiteSpace = False
    
    Set myXSLT = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    myXSLT.async = False
    myXSLT.preserveWhiteSpace = False

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Comment: i am using this to create the xml, but that is not my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
FileName = "C:\teste\" & Replace(Replace(Me!YourCombobox.Value, ",", "_"), " ", "") & "xml"

file: myXML.Save FileName
```

Comment: Thanks, it work :) I have to change Me! to Forms!frmMyForm! and that work.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the values like this.
I've added an additional test for null, because if no value is selected on one or more of the ComboBoxes it will throw an error.

```
If IsNull(ComboBox1.Value) Or IsNull(ComboBox2.Value) Or IsNull(ComboBox3.Value) Or IsNull(ComboBox4.Value) Then
     MsgBox ("Not all values selected!")
Else
    Dim myFileName As String
    myFileName = "C:\teste\" & ComboBox1.Value & "_" & ComboBox2.Value & "_" & ComboBox3.Value & "_" & ComboBox4.Value & ".xml"
    myXML.Save myFileName
End If
```

Comment: I already tried that, but i get: run-time error '424' object required

Comment: Then this should have been your question. I think you just misspelled the name of one ComboBox, because this can throw the 424 error.